# DiscordJS Bot "connected to Discord more than 1000 times" in 24 hours while not doing so

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am hosting a Discord JS bot using my phone (with Termux, is this a problem?), but I kept getting this "`It appears your bot, Siri Bot, has connected to Discord more than 1000 times within a short time period. Since this kind of behavior is usually a result of a bug we have gone ahead and reset your bot's token.`" from Discord, the strange thing is that the bot is rarely used and there is no way there was 1000 connects made in 24 hours.

I checked my code and there is no loops that connects to Discord, and when I put a `console.log(1)` next to `client.login()` it was only printed out once only. (So it's not caused by logging in a bunch of times)

I am also aware that Discord.js automatically reconnects when it was disconnected, but as `client.once('ready')` did not gave me anything, I assume it wasn't caused by my bot being disconnected.

I searched everywhere but I couldn't find a solution to this, please help.

Here's my `index.js` file (it's just average Discord bot code): https://github.com/Siriusmart/SiriBot/blob/main/index.js

Comment: How does Termux run and sleep a process? If the node process resets each time you turn your phone on that may be the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android sometimes will close internet when your phone goes sleep, you can disable it in your Settings.
When there is no internet access, Discord.js will lost connection with Discord (a.k.a Logout), after you wake your phone, Discord.js detected internet is back, so it reconnect to Discord (a.k.a Login).

By the way, reconnect won't emit `ready` event, it will emit `shardReconnecting`

Docs: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/errors.html#websocket-and-network-errors
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-shardReconnecting

Comment: thanks, i switched to an actual bot host and problem resolved, looks like its really my phone's problem :<)